# textfield after text (in div) always displays in new line

Tags: html, css, position

i want some text and textfields to properly display in the same line and make an line break after each textfield. First i had all buttons in a class which had a absolute position, but i think there is a better solution.

At the moment i have it this way

```
<form action="" method="get" name="pdaten" >
<p><div class="text">Vorname</div><input class="button" id="vname"  type="text" /></p>
<p><div class="text">Nachname</div><input class="button"  id="nname"  type="text" /></p>
<p><div class="text">Geburtstag</div><input class="button" id="gebdat" type="text" /></p>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form{
    padding-left:1em;

}

.button{
    position:relative;
    left:0%;
}

.text{
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
}
```

The thing is, the textfields are always displayed in the next line, instead of the same as the div in which the text is. I could use a span, but than i dont know how to position them correctly, since i want the textfields to be exactly underneath the last one.

Anybody can help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to your text class.

```
.text{
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nGLHw/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `div`s `display` property to `inline`, like this:

```
.text {
    display: inline;
}
```

This will make the `div`s behave like inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `div`'s are block element, you can change the behavior by changing the `display` property value to `inline-display`

```
.text{
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UcKVx/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left; clear:right;` to your .button elements

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add `display: inline-block` for your div

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mAsxZ/1/